# What are Test Functions in QFT (physics context)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, wavefunction, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

In terms of mode function solutions of the KG equation, the field operator can be written as
$$ \hat{\phi}(x) = \int_{R^3} d^3\textbf{p}\space \left(u_\textbf{p} \hat{a}_\textbf{p}+ u^*_\textbf{p}\hat{a}^\dagger_\textbf{p}\right). \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

The positive frequency mode functions span a one-particle Hilbert space from which the bosonic Fock space of the theory can be constructed. Mathematically, equation \eqref{eq1} is an abuse of notation as the "field operator" presented here is actually pointwise representation of the operator-valued distribution $\hat{\phi}[f]$, which yields an operator on the Fock space once smeared with a Schwartz function $f$ ([see p.50 of Chatterjee’s lecture notes](https://souravchatterjee.su.domains/qft-lectures-combined.pdf#page23)), i.e.

$$ \hat{\phi}[f] = \int d^4\textbf{x}\space f(x) \hat{\phi}(x).\tag{2} $$

I’ve read that this is done so to "smoothen" the distribution and, intuitively, to account for the fact that a particle is never perfectly localized; theory fails at high energies etc… However, until now, this test function is not mentioned in any of my courses, so I fail to make its connection to the expressions I see in physics. First, I thought these test functions are the mode functions we get from solving the EoM, and from a QM perspective, related to the wave functions of one-particle states, although they’re fundamentally different entities. This also clarified the (historical, problematic) notion of "second quantization". But, they seem to be independent, for example the plane wave solutions coming from the Fourier transform would be included in $\phi(x)$ and $f$ would be something else. Also, how does then one choose a test function? I know they have to be smooth and rapidly decreasing.

Comment: Related: [Spaces of test functions and distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_of_test_functions_and_distributions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not seeing test functions in typical physicist texts on QFT because QFT generally does *not* operate at the level of mathematical rigor where it would consistently care about the notion of quantum fields being operator-valued distributions and not operator-valued functions.

In contrast to many other areas of physics where we at least in *principle* know a fully mathematically rigorous formulation of the theory, the correct rigorous formulation of *general* QFT - and in particular of the kind of QFTs we use to describe the universe, i.e. the Standard Model - is *not* known. The formulation of an SM-like theory in a fully rigorous framework is one of the [millenium problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_existence_and_mass_gap) and still unsolved.

However, indeed one approach to rigorously formulate QFT is to think of quantum fields as operator-valued distributions. A [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) is *defined* as a linear map on some space of functions, and the functions in that space are called "test functions". A common choice is to talk about *tempered* distributions, which by definition are the dual space of the space of [Schwartz functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), which are functions rapidly decreasing at infinity so that many common integrals can converge without issues. That is, test functions are just part of the definition of what a distribution is, not something with immediate physical meaning.

You rarely have to "choose" a specific test function, much like you would never really choose some specific value of $x$ to evaluate $\phi(x)$ at in the usual non-rigorous approach.

Comment: Thank you this clarifies some of the issues, but I still have one question. Is there any relation between the Hilbert space H of one-particle states (solutions of eom) and the Schwartz space? In p.27 of the lecture notes I linked in the question, they seem to make use of the creation/ annihilation operators and the aforementioned H to define operator-valued distributions on H, which is then used to construct the field (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @Ef00 Not directly, no. The relation between the quantum field as a distribution and the creation/annihilation distributions on the Fock space is written on page 48 of your notes. Note that the quantum field is a distribution on Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$, while the one-particle space (on which the c/a distributions live) is the space of $L^2$-classes of functions on the mass shell $X_m$ - these are *different* spaces

Comment: Ah, alright. Thanks, this distinction helps a lot, I completely missed that. One final question, the action of the c/a distribution corresponds to the naive attempt of "quantizing" the wave function, hence the name second quantization, right?

Comment: @Ef00 Yes, you can view it like that.

Answer (score 2):

[Test functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_of_test_functions_and_distributions) are the objects that occur in the [theory of distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) that makes mathematical sense of   Dirac's  delta finction. They are smooth (*i.e.* infinitely differentiable) functions that vanish rapidly at infinity.